# Google search results: getting page with actual links on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, google-search

I use an app called Offline Pages to save web pages on my ipad. Often save my search results and all of the Links on that page, then I don't have to wait for pages to load, so I can explore the results more quickly. Whenever I try to do this with google none of the links ie results get downloaded correctly. I find myself frequently repeating mya searches on bing so that I can do this.

My question is this:
**Using only my ipad, How can i get a page of results from a Google search such that all of the links are to the actual URLs of the results and are not links that just redirect to those pages?**